# How to calculate $\int \arctan(e^x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

How to calculate the integral

$$\int \arctan(e^x)\,dx$$

I tried using $u=-x$, with no luck; and $u=e^x$ with no luck, either ...

I know that for every $x>0$,

$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But, I don't know how to use this fact.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer may disappoint you. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arctan%28e%5Ex%29

Comment: Is there a reason to expect you can find a closed form for this integral? The closed form Wolfram Alpha gives is in terms of the function $Li_2,$ a “logarithmic integral” function, which is to say, it probably can’t be written in terms of “elementary” functions.

Comment: I guess one has to go to the guts of algebraic differentiable fields ( like Liouville) to check that the the integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions (diffuse properly there)

Comment: If you are looking to find a definite integral relating to this expression, then you can mention it , perhaps it could have a closed form. Alternately, you can explore Liouville's theorem [stated here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf) and check it out for yourself, with the caveat that it may contain mathematics beyond your reading. The statement can be deconvoluted for your purpose.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ... I think $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is a dilogarithm, not a logarithmic integral.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: if WA didn't find a closed-form, odds are high that there isn't one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: of course. Still, someone who is interested in theses matters may want to prove it through the ways of algebraic differentiable fields; as Liouville did for $e^{x^2}$ or Chebyshev did for certain binomial type of integrals

Answer (score 4):

The indefinite integral is

$$\int \arctan e^x\,dx 
\overset{t=e^x}= \int \frac{\tan^{-1}t}t\,dt= \operatorname{Ti}_2(t)+C
$$

where $\operatorname{Ti}_2(t)$ is the inverse tangent integral function.

---

Edit: As indicated in the comments, it is the definite integral below that is of OP’s interest

\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \arctan e^x \,dx 
\overset{x\to -x}=& \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \arctan e^{-x}\,dx \\
= &\frac 12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}( \arctan e^x+\arctan e^{-x})\,dx \\
= &\frac 12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac\pi2\,dx =\frac{\pi^2}2\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know what $Ti$ means, and I can't use that in my homework... Any other ideas?

Comment: @TheCalc What is your homework then? Perhaps it would be better to mention its relation to the question you have asked.

Comment: I need to calculate $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi}(4arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx$

Comment: @TheCalc I see! Now you can see that the antiderivative is not easy to find, so you need to play with definite integral tricks. Just to confirm, the answer is $0$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, you are right!

Comment: @TheCalc : In many cases one can find an exact value of a definite integral without being able to find the corresponding indefinite integral.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I will look into it now, thanks!

Comment: @TheCalc Great, that's good to know.

Comment: @TheCalc - see the edit for the result of the corresponding definite integral

Comment: Ad hocery in the highest!

Answer (score 0):

Differentiated and integrated to see if DE would simplify, but did not.

Prime indicates differentiation wrt x

$$\tan y'= e^x.  \text{differentiating, } \sec^{2}y^{'} y^{''}= e^x$$

Plug in and simplify

$$ 2 y^{''} \text{ = sech x } $$

```
`Mathematica` gives 

y=x ArcTan[Tanh[x/2]] + C[1] + x C[2] + 
    1/2 I (x (Log[1 - I e^-x] - Log[1 + I e^-x]) + 
       PolyLog[2, -I e^-x] - PolyLog[2, I e^-x])].
```